# MYSQL won't drop the default value for a timestamp

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am trying to drop the default value of a timestamp column.

My DDL looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE bills
(
    ...
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1971-01-06 00:00:00',
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
);
```

When I try any of the following:

```
ALTER TABLE bills ALTER COLUMN created_at DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE bills ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT NULL;

ALTER TABLE bills MODIFY COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP NULL;
ALTER TABLE bills MODIFY COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL;

ALTER TABLE bills CHANGE COLUMN created_at created_at TIMESTAMP NULL;
ALTER TABLE bills CHANGE COLUMN created_at created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

The MYSQL shell says it has executed correctly.

However, when I check the DDL again, it is clear nothing has changed.

On the other hand, I can alter the default value to a specified value like so:

```
ALTER TABLE bills ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT '1972-02-02 00:00:00';
```

And it updates correctly.

Note that the columns are nullable (as you can see by the DDL) and I have put null data values in the "create_at" column.

The MYSQL version I am using is as v5.7.12

Here is more details about the version I am using:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CHANGE COLUMN or MODIFY COLUMN versions of the ALTER TABLE syntax. These require you to specify all the attributes of the column that you want to carry over from the old to the new definition (CHANGE also requires the name so that you can rename at the same time).

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE bills CHANGE COLUMN created_at created_at TIMESTAMP NULL; 
ALTER TABLE bills MODIFY COLUMN updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL;
```

Here's a sqlfiddle so you can see it working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/303110/3

---

Update

Have you checked the value of the EXPLICIT_DEFAULTS_FOR_TIMESTAMP variable?

Following on from my comments below, I've now succeeded in getting both of your statements to work in mysql 5.7 by setting the variable EXPLICIT_DEFAULTS_FOR_TIMESTAMP =  1;

I'm afraid I can't properly explain the purpose of this variable except to say that it appears to be intended to disable some 'nonstandard' behaviours in TIMESTAMP fields. It's documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp).

I'll quote one bit of this

> By default, explicit_defaults_for_timestamp is disabled, which enables
>   the nonstandard behaviors.

Personally, I think this is the wrong way round, you ought to set the variable to allow the use of 'nonstandard' behaviours if you wish to go down that path. I'd call that a bug.

In your case, and assuming this actually works on your system, disabling the 'nonstandard' behaviour would allow the 'standard' syntax for changing a column default to work.

This is the output on my system

```
paul@zoltan:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

mysql> SET @@SESSION.EXPLICIT_DEFAULTS_FOR_TIMESTAMP = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop table bills;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> create table bills (
    ->   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1971-01-06 00:00:00',
    ->   updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 01:00:01'
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)

mysql> alter table bills alter column created_at drop default;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table bills alter column created_at set default null;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table bills alter column updated_at drop default;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table bills alter column updated_at set default null;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table bills\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: bills
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `bills` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I tried the above commands and they bizarrely don't work. I've updated the question to show more examples I tried.

Comment: @YahyaUddin To confuse matters further, I run exactly the same version as you on my Ubuntu 17.10 laptop. The first of your statements runs OK for me but leaves the columns with an ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the output of show create table. The second of your statements fails with "ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created_at'".  In sqlfiddle (mysql 5.6) your first statement fails with the error "Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value". The versions I gave you work on both platforms. Could you post the full output of show create table.

Comment: @YahyaUddin I've updated my answer with something else you can check.